# after applying clearfix hack to figure tag, the figcaption gets excluded and goes out of the figure

Tags: html, css, web, vs-web-site-project, clearfix

```
@media(min-width: 1071) {
        .align-left {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            max-height: 350 ;
            max-width: 450 ;
        }

        .align-center {
            float: inherit;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            max-height: 350 ;
            max-width: 450 ;
        }

        .align-right {
            float: right;
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            max-height: 350 ;
            max-width: 450 ;
        }

        .column::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        
        #blog {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
```

}
it is getting difficult to upload the picture but please try to understand my question<== the figcaption is inside the figure tag with img but only the img is getting displayed with the bg color of figure the figcaption is not included in the bg color applied to figure ==>